# Does the internally called resize() of vector also default initialize values?

Tags: c++, vector

As per default (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) `resize()` on a vector will call the default constructor.

Suppose I call `push_back()` on a vector and it resizes due to that - will it then also initialize the newly allocated space? If so - why? Leaving things uninitialized first could be efficient if the client calls for example `push_back()` because then one could simply copy the object as a whole instead of having to use the copy constructor as it would be the case if the memory location would already have been initialized.

Comment: Suppose calling `push_back` doesn't call `resize()`...

Comment: Seriously guys, calm down with the downvotes.

Comment: "If n is greater than the current container size, the content is expanded by inserting at the end as many elements as needed to reach a size of n. If val is specified, the new elements are initialized as copies of val, otherwise, they are **value-initialized**." Looking at your "reference" it actually says that `resize()` does value initialize it. It's nowhere said that vector uses it after `push_back`s though.

Comment: @OP You're confusing `std::vector<T>::resize()` with `std::vector<T>::reserve()` actually.

Comment: Yes I mixed something up here.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` won't call the `resize()` function when it runs out of space with a `push_back()` call. Also there are two related functions in the vector.

[`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) which reserves space for more elements but doesn't call any constructor on them. Also it doesn't change the size of the vector.

[`resize()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) which gives the vector the new size. When you got an vector with 5 elements and call `vector.resize(10)` calling `vector.size()` afterwards would also return 10 since it fills up with [*value-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) elements.

When the vector runs out of space due to calling `push_back()` on it it'll most likely call `reserve()` or an internal version of it.